# How to structure ViewControllers using Storyboard for SplitView iPad app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to build the interface for an app that looks like this:
[image: image of app]

I want to use the Storyboard to create the views, but I'm having trouble figuring out how now.  I've dropped a SplitViewController that is hooked up to 2 navigation controllers:  MasterNavigationController, and DetailNavigationController (Master is the left side menu and Detail the right side).

I was starting to build all my ViewControllers in storyboard. Then build NSArrays to hold the various ViewController stacks needed for each of the Master's menu items. So when a user taps on a menu item, I'd load the corresponding ViewController stack into the DetailNavigationController using this method:

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

But now I'm thinking, I should create a separate DetailNavigationController for each of the menu items.  For example:

- RecentOrdersNavigationController
- CustomersNavigationController
- ItemsNavigationController
- ...

Then when a user taps a menu item, the entire DetailNavigationController changes to the appropriate one.

How should I be structuring the the interface while using storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate viewController for each detail view. You want your code to be separate since it can get confusing fast with all the different functionality for each view. From there, you can easily swap out the the detail.

Subclass UISplitViewController and set your root splitViewController to that class. Then add this method to your UISplitViewController subclass:

```
-(void)setDetailControllerTo:(UIViewController *)detailController withNavControllerTitle:(NSString *)title {
[detailController view]; // this line forces the viewDidLoad method to be called

if (title) {
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [navController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
    detailController.title = title;

    NSArray *viewControllers=@[self.mainController.viewControllers[0],navController];
    self.mainController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
} else {
    NSArray *viewControllers=@[self.mainController.viewControllers[0],detailController];
    self.mainController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
}
```

}

To call this method do something like this from the master view controller in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method

```
FixedSplitViewController *splitController = (FixedSplitViewController*) self.splitViewController;

CurrentEventViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CurrentEventViewController"];
// add any setup code here
[splitController setDetailControllerTo:controller withNavControllerTitle:@"Current Event"];
```

If you wish to keep the master view visible in portrait rotation, add this method to the SplitViewController subclass:

```
-(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return NO;
}
```

A lot of my projects require the splitviewcontroller to always show the master view so I use this subclass to keep the master view from hiding on portrait rotation.